# Angular mat-datepicker weird behavior

Tags: angular, mat-datepicker

I have the following HTML code for datepicker :

```
<mat-form-field class="input-form">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (click)="picker.open()" [formControl]="fieldIndividuEducation.control">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-hint align="end">label</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

I need to get the date and then insert it in PGSQL database. I have the following code to retrieve it :

```
if(element.type == 'date' && element.control.value !== null) {
    let month = element.control.value.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    let day = element.control.value.getUTCDate() + 1;
    let year = element.control.value.getUTCFullYear();
    value = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
}
```

The "+1" is because by default the selected date is one day before the selection, I don't know why..
But if I select the 01 May 2020 the result of `value` is : 2020-4-31

Do you have any idea to retrieve the correct selected date ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are getting UTC date and not the local date which depending on where you are could give value with one day difference. If you just do `element.control.value.getMonth()` you will get the month according to local time. Also, remember that the Months start from 0, so January will be '0' and December '11'